# How to upload an attachment/file to the Gmail compose window using JS (google chrome extension app)

Tags: javascript, file-upload, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a chrome extension built using JS, and looking for a solution to upload files/attachments to Gmail's compose window from a document management system.

I have the file details (binary data) of the files to upload. And no visibility on next steps to interact with the compose window and uploading file to it.

Can anyone help me in guiding through this please.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Class GmailAttachment](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-attachment).

Here is an example code snippet from the docs.

```
 // Logs information about any attachments in the first 100 inbox threads.
 var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0, 100);
 var msgs = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(threads);
 for (var i = 0 ; i < msgs.length; i++) {
   for (var j = 0; j < msgs[i].length; j++) {
     var attachments = msgs[i][j].getAttachments();
     for (var k = 0; k < attachments.length; k++) {
       Logger.log('Message "%s" contains the attachment "%s" (%s bytes)',
                  msgs[i][j].getSubject(), attachments[k].getName(), attachments[k].getSize());
     }
   }
 }
```

Also, you can to refer [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/drafts/create) as a guide on creating gmail drafts.